# Is the natural projection of flag varieties a flat morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a field k (of characteristic zero) with parabolic subgroup $P$ and Borel $B \subset P$.

Is the natural projection  $ \pi: G/B \rightarrow G/P $ of flag varieties then  flat?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to see this, but as both are smooth one can observe that by Miracle Flatness (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_criterion_for_flatness#Miracle_flatness_theorem) it suffices to show that the fibers of $\pi$ all have the same dimension, but the fiber over a point $x$ of $G/P$ is isomorphic to $(P/B)_x$, which has dimension independent of $x$.